# Split a string on every space untill the second colon is found

Tags: php, regex

I was looking for a way to split a string on every space, untill a second colon is found. If it's helpful for the answer, the language I'm doing this in is PHP. Basically what I want is the following string:

```
:foo!bar@cookie.net strawberry cheesecake :hello world: this is a message!
```

to be split into the following array:

```
array(
    [0] => ":foo!bar@cookie.net",
    [1] => "strawberry",
    [2] => "cheesecake",
    [3] => ":hello world: this is a message!"
);
```

How would I achieve this? Note that the colons are not guaranteed to be there. The input string may differ, like just `Hello World`.

Answer (score 1):

Split the data in two steps.  Split the input string on the space before the second colon into a 2-element array. Then replace the first element with the elements produced when exploding on its spaces.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/fETHh))

```
$string = ':foo!bar@cookie.net strawberry cheesecake :hello world: this is a message!';

$result = preg_split('/[^:]*:[^:]*\K /', $string, 2);
array_unshift($result, ...explode(' ', array_shift($result)));
var_export($result);
```

Comment: OP might as well be in the space or enjoying some cocktails on Barbados. the question is over a decade old...

Comment: I am very aware of the age of the question.  I predominately answer old questions because 99.8% of all new questions SHOULD be closed as duplicates.  (but I'm sure you already know my philosophies)

Comment: I know your philosophy. And you're right, of course. The question just popped up and I couldn't control myself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You would first split on colon. Then split the first on space

Example

```
$colon = explode(",",$str);
$space = explode(" ",$colon[1]);
```

Then colon[2]
Will have rest of string and space will have the space separated parts

Comment: `$colon = explode(",", $str, 3)`, or it won't work correctly if the rest of the string has colons (as in OP's example); also, you need to put a colon back into `$colon[1]` to get OP's `":foo..."`.

Comment: And what if the input string does not have any colons at all, but i do need to know about the first space-part? Yes I could do some if-else trickery but I would love a more elegant solution :P

Comment: If it's about colons, why do you split on commata?